# NFS activity locks desktop during any user initiated file activity

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint, nas, nfs

This is a funny little issue that has been happening for a while and I have learnt to work around but would prefer to resolve completely.

My desktop PC is running linux mint 17.1 cinnamon.
Core I5, 32GB RAM, 2 internal SSD drives

It connects via ethernet to an asus rt-n12 running tomato in wireless client mode, which connects to the router downstairs.
When it connected directly to the main router (different location and router) this issue did not occur, only since having a wireless link in the middle. Have tried multiple wireless adapters and also swapped out most hardware since this first occured.

Connected to the router downstairs is a synology NAS with lots of storage, mounted via NFS.

Whenever there is any heavy connection activity from my PC to the NAS there is a high risk of the desktop interactivity completely locking up.

When this occurs everything continues to run, videos/music will play in the background, can move the mouse etc, but any clicks are not registered. Sometimes it locks up for seconds, sometimes minutes and occasionally never recovers.
When it does recover the previous few clicks or actions happen in quick succession.

Strangely it is rarely the NAS traffic alone that triggers this, but normally heavy NAS traffic in combination with a simple task such as reading or writing a small text file on the local SSD - always file related, but not specific to any one disk. Also always user initiated, logs and other background tasks are reading and writing without issue.

Any thoughts on the possible cause or solutions?